# Notifying log errors via email using logstash

Tags: email, smtp, logstash

I'm working on sending a notification email using Logstash if an error occurs.

I'm using the email plugin coming as part of logstash : http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/email

On checking the documentation the To address seems to be the only required field and it didn't work when i specified it to my gmail id : pjesudhas@gmail.com

Is it required to have any other mail server running in my system for this to work, if so what do i have to do. Please let me know your thoughts.

```
email{
options => [ "smtpIporHost", "smtp.gmail.com",
         "port", "587",
         "userName", "pjesudhas@gmail.com",
         "password", "mypassword"
       ]
from => "pjesudhas@gmail.com"
subject => "Error status"
to => "pjesudhas@gmail.com"
body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{@message}"
htmlbody => "<h2>%{matchName}</h2><br/><br/><h3>Full Event</h3><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{@message}</div>"
}
```

I  also tried  including my gmail id settings based on reading a tutorial but it didn't work either,please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail SMTP requires the to and from addresses to use a specific format: `<example@example.org>`

Try

```
email{
options => [ "smtpIporHost", "smtp.gmail.com",
         "port", "587",
         "userName", "pjesudhas@gmail.com",
         "password", "mypassword"
       ]
from => "<pjesudhas@gmail.com>"
subject => "Error status"
to => "<pjesudhas@gmail.com>"
body => "Here is the event line that occured: %{@message}"
htmlbody => "<h2>%{matchName}</h2><br/><br/><h3>Full Event</h3><br/><br/><div align='center'>%{@message}</div>"
}
```